# Get list of MAC addresses on one port with SNMP WALK

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement, snmp, cisco

I need to grab all the mac addresses that are on the same port.

Let’s say you have a basic router that is plugged into the wall. From that router two computers are plugged into those ports. I want to be able to find out what MAC addresses are plugged into those ports.

I **MUST** be able to use this for web development (PHP / SQL)
SNMP would be the best option if it’s possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Currently we are using SNMPWALK to find a single mac address to the port, but now we will have multiple users in the same port.

Comment: Realted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931225/snmp-mapping-mac-address-to-switch-port

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to read the CAM table of the switch?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a program called LanTopolog. Its an application that i use for network discovery , visualization and monitoring.  It uses SNMP and ICMP and shows all the mac addresses of my ports. You just need to know your IP address for your computer and switches. Heres the website; http://www.lantopolog.com/download.html.

Answer (score 0):

snmpwalk should return all the MACs it sees on a given port.  SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2 .17.4.3.1.1 (aka .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1) will give you the MAC for each bridge port.  Then you need to match the bridge port ID up with the port number.  It's best practice to check that every time you run your check rather than assuming bridgeport IDs will always map to the same physical ports.